# overriding functions of running process in linux

Tags: linux, ld-preload

I am curious to know, how to override functions of a running process in Linux so that process should call my functions first.

we can use `LD_PRELOAD` for overriding of function in a binary but it does not work in case of already running process. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

What LD_PRELOAD allows you to do is force loading a shared object before any other. So if a function is already provided by this custom shared object, it will not be loaded again from the "standard" shared object.

In your case you want to modify an already loaded function. I believe that is not possible.

This would clearly be a security risk.

Most operating systems implement DEP and ASLR which would prevent modifing and predicting the shared object position in memory.